# Groovy - JsonSlurper Parsing JSON file

Tags: json, groovy

I have a JSON document structured similar to below, and I am trying to parse it in Groovy.  Basically for each School (School Info), I want to grab the `SCHOOL_COUNTRY` and other fields.  I am trying this code below but it is not returning what I need.  For each school listed (1,000's), I want to grab only specific parts, for instance:

```
def parseJSON(long id) {

    JSONFile fileInstance = JSONFile.get(id)
    def json = new JsonSlurper().setType(RELAX).parse(new FileReader(fileInstance.filePath))
    def schoolInfo = json.SCHOOL_INFO
    def schoolName = json.SCHOOL_INFO.SCHOOL_NAME
    schoolInfo.each {
       render(schoolInfo.SCHOOL_NAME)
    }
}
```

So basically for each school, just print out the name of the school. The JSON structure:

```
[{
    "SCHOOL_INFO": {
        "SCHOOL_COUNTRY": "Finland",   
        "SCHOOL NAME": "Findland Higher Learning"              
     },
     "LOCATION": {                  
         "LONGITUDE": "24.999",                   
         "LATITUDE": "61.001"
     }
}]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the only bug but you can't read `schoolInfo.SCHOOL_NAME` in `each`. `SCHOOL_NAME` is property of `json.SCHOOL_INFO` so `it.SCHOOL_NAME` is proper way to access it. Take look at example below:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def jsonAsText = '''[{
    "SCHOOL_INFO": {
        "SCHOOL_COUNTRY": "Finland",   
        "SCHOOL NAME": "Findland Higher Learning"              
    },
    "LOCATION": {                  
        "LONGITUDE": "24.999",                   
        "LATITUDE": "61.001"
    }
}]'''

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonAsText)

def schoolInfo= json.SCHOOL_INFO
schoolInfo.each{
    println it."SCHOOL NAME"
}
```

It prints:

```
Findland Higher Learning
```

Answer (score 4):

Here You go:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def t = """[{
    "SCHOOL_INFO": {
        "SCHOOL_COUNTRY": "Finland",   
        "SCHOOL NAME": "Findland Higher Learning"              
     },
     "LOCATION": {                  
         "LONGITUDE": "24.999",                   
         "LATITUDE": "61.001"
     }
}]"""

def slurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(t)
slurper.each {
    println it.SCHOOL_INFO."SCHOOL NAME"
}
```

I'm not sure if there should be `_` sign in *SCHOOL NAME*.

Answer (score 1):

```
println it.SCHOOL_INFO."SCHOOL NAME"
```

This should work without _ sign.